# Not able to add OkHttp client to Apollo Client (Apollo-kotin Version 3)

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, okhttp, apollo-kotlin

I am not able to attach my Okhttp client to Apollo client. I can't able to find `okhttpclient()` method in `ApolloClient.Builder` class. It shows "Cannot resolve method 'okHttpClient' in 'Builder'" error. I'm using apollo version 3.

build.gradle (Project)

```
classpath "com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-gradle-plugin:3.6.1"
```

build.gradle (App)

```
// Graphql
def apollo3GraphqlVersion = '3.6.1'
implementation "com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-runtime:$apollo3GraphqlVersion"
implementation "com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-rx3-support:$apollo3GraphqlVersion"
```

Client.class

```
apolloClient = new ApolloClient.Builder()
    .serverUrl(baseUrl)
    .okHttpClient() // error "Cannot resolve method 'okHttpClient' in 'Builder'"
    .build();
```

Comment: where you able to find how to link okhttpclient with apolloclient?

Comment: I downgraded to Apollo version 2, and was able to add it. Still not able to add in Version 3.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late but I found a way to do this (version 3.8.2) :

```
import com.apollographql.apollo3.ApolloClient
import com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.DefaultHttpEngine;

apolloClient = new ApolloClient.Builder()
    .serverUrl("")
    .httpEngine(new DefaultHttpEngine(okHttpClient))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).